# Unable to set up ExternalIp port forwarding in openshift orgin pods

Tags: ssh, openshift, openshift-origin

I have a use case where I am running services on my local machine which is behind a router behind a NAT, so I can't port forward to my public IP. The only way to do it is via ssh tunneling or a VPN, for both I would need an exposed port to connect from my local

So,
i tried setting up my yml config with external ip,
and it looks like this :

> `spec:
>   ports:
>   - name: 8022-tcp
>   protocol: TCP
>   port: 8022
>   targetPort: 8022
>   nodePort: 31043
>   - name: 8080-tcp
>   protocol: TCP
>   port: 8080
>   targetPort: 8080
>   nodePort: 30826
>   selector:
>   deploymentconfig: remote-forward
>   clusterIP: 172.30.83.16
>   type: LoadBalancer
>   externalIPs:
>   - 10.130.79.198
>   deprecatedPublicIPs:
>   - 10.130.79.198
>   sessionAffinity: None`

If I understand correctly here 10.130.79.198, is the IP I will need to connect to from my local ssh on port 31043 which then forwards it to the service port 8022 which then forwards to container port 8022 where the ssh server is running.
The problem is that I am not able to connect to this external IP.

ssh logs:

> "debug1: connect to address 10.130.79.198 port 31043: Connection timed out"

I got this external IP from the `pod -> dashboard page -> external IP`. Is this external IP needs to be configured anywhere or is my above config has any issue with the setup?